# An alternative to counter objects in for loops

Tags: python

In the below code snippet, is there a more pythonic way to iterate over each object in a list while increasing the index of another? I use this idiom frequently, thinking there is a better method.

```
# Creates a dictionary with normalized values for the dataset.
def exp_pull(sample, gene):
    sample_name = {genes: values for genes, values in 
                    zip([v for i, (j, k) in set_list[int(sample) - 1:int(sample)] 
                    for v in j], mean_values)}
    return round(sample_name.get(gene), 3)


# Pulls normalized expression values for particular genes for all samples.
genes_of_interest = ['ERG', 'ETV1', 'ETV4', 'ETV5']

count = 0
for gene in genes_of_interest:
    print '\n'
    print genes_of_interest[count], ':'
    for file in file_list:
        print file, ": ", exp_pull(file_list.index(file) + 1, 
                                    genes_of_interest[count])
    count += 1
```

Comment: Why not just use `gene`? No need to count *at all*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have an index on the loop **at all**; you already have the `gene` element in your list. Instead, you want to get a counter for the `file_list` loop, it appears, and avoid the (expensive) `file_list.index()` call. Using the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you just that:

```
for gene in genes_of_interest:
    print '\n{}:'.format(gene)
    for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
        print '{}: {}'.format(file, exp_pull(i, gene))
```

This uses string formatting to combine the output in an efficient and compact manner.

Now the first argument is *always* an integer, so you can drop the `int()` calls in `exp_pull()`. You also were slicing just *one* element out of `set_list()`, so by passing in the `file_list` index (**not** plus one) you can simplify your overly complex `exp_pull()` to:

```
def exp_pull(sample, gene):
    if sample >= len(set_list):
        # no such entry in set_list
        return 0.0
    i, (j, k) = set_list[sample]
    sample_name = dict(zip(j, mean_values))
    return round(sample_name.get(gene, 0), 3)
```

This drops the need for nested comprehensions all together; I also added a default to the `sample_name.get()` call, as `round()` will throw an exception if the normal default `None` is returned.

I suspect the rest of your program could do with similar simplifications; you may want to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to see what else can be adjusted.

Comment: Everything looks good for the first code block. However the second throws the error:
i, (j, k) = set_list[sample]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user2277435: Right, in your original code the list slice could indeed give you an empty list, then an empty dictionary, then an error on the last line for the `round()`. Will adjust.

Comment: The modified code block is giving zero entries now for pulled values for one of the files, will look into it more and post on codereview, linking back.

Comment: @user2277435: that means you have more entries in `file_lists` than you have in `set_list`.

Comment: The extra entry in file_list comes from disregarding the first index in command line arguments passed, as it contains the script name is sys. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31617/code-correctness-and-refinement-for-quantile-normalization

Comment: @user2277435: then skip that by looping over `file_list[1:]` instead. Or remove it early, by using `file_list.pop(0)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for indx, gene in enumerate(genes_of_interest):
    print '\n'
    print genes_of_interest[indx], ':'
    for indx2, file in enumerate(file_list, 1):
        print file, ": ", exp_pull(indx2, 
                                    genes_of_interest[indx])
```

But either way, this is pointless. You're already iterating through the list, giving each item the name of `gene`. There's no need to access the exact same element through indexing, when you can just use `gene`, eg:

```
for gene in genes_of_interest:
    print '\n'
    print gene, ':'
    for indx, file in enumerate(file_list, 1):
        print file, ": ", exp_pull(indx, 
                                    gene)
```

`enumerate()` takes a second argument, *start*. Instead of starting at 0, you can start at *n*.

Comment: You forgot to actually **use** `enumerate()`. And it is not needed, since `gene == genes_of_interest[indx]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fixed, I think. Thanks for being there once again Martijn :)

Comment: `enumerate()` takes a second argument, the starting count; no need to `+ 1` each time when you start counting from 1. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're such a legend. Btw, did you see my tweet :)

Comment: Yup, did see your tweet. :-)